# Swift 3 How to display different data for each item in index UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I made a UICollectionView in my app but I can't figure out how to display different data for each cell I'm stuck with the same image I set it to in storyboard

the searching I've done has not resulted in any tutorials but I know that I customize my data in the UICollectionViewCell custom class

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    //drawing a blank here...
}
```

if you could help me out I just want to put a button, two images and  a couple labels (2-3) for each cell (there will be about 12 cells and I need them to have different data for each because i am trying to make a character selection screen)

with my current setup

```
class CharacterViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

var array = [UIImage(named: "ideal image"),UIImage(named: "ideal image"),UIImage(named: "ideal image")]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return array.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "FirstCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! FirstCollectionViewCell

    return cell
}
```

}

i am able to display three of the exact same image but i need the cells to have separate customizable data i know all about .xib files and cocoa touch classes i use em all the time

one site i saw suggested using .xib files for each cell which i dont mind setting up but i need to know how to register the .xib files to be displayed as a cell if you know how could you help me out?

here is my cell

[image: image for cell]

you guys are a huge help i think i know how to do it

1. make cells with custom .xib files
2. register .xib cells to array
3. load array of cells into collectionView
4. enjoy custom collectionView

Comment: Maybe, you should try the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37315466/how-to-load-custom-cell-xib-in-uicollectionview-cell-using-swift

Comment: its working now just one issue its saying " Ambiguous reference to member 'collectionView(_:numberOfItemsInSection:)'" anybody know how to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more than 1 way to achieve it. Bu your code it seems customcell is used
The code for it

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

 let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

      cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

         if indexPath.section == 0 {

      cell.imageView.image = image
                }
         if indexPath.section == 1 {

      cell.imageView.image = image
                }
      return cell
 }

override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
              return 2 // whatever you want
}

         //2
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

         return searches[section].searchResults.count // if each section have same cell

         if section == 0 {
                return 2
            } else if section == 1 {
                return 3
         }
}
```

[Link to customcell for collectionview](https://www.raywenderlich.com/136159/uicollectionview-tutorial-getting-started)

Comment: Best advice create section if you want so much different data on each cell.

Comment: It depend upon you on using multiple xib or one xib and reusing it like I mention in my updated code

Comment: i will not be reusing xib it is easier i need to display multiple .xibs in the collectionView

Answer (score 2):

In your controller you have to set this:

```
    Class yourController : UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{...
 //at some point 
yourCollectionView.delegate = self
yourCollectionView.dataSource = self
```

and then you include this method and you'll be able to load the data you want in each cell:

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell: yourCell = collection.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: nameCelda, for: indexPath) as! yourCell
//dataArrayOrWhatever -> An array of data for each row
        let dataForCelll =  dataArrayOrWhatever[indexPath.row]
//functions defined on your yourCell.Swift
        cell.setImage(imageName: someMethodWithDataForImage(data: dataForCell))
        cell.setTitle(title: someMethodWithDataForTitle(data: dataForCell))
```

Hope it helps you ;)

Comment: could you please be more specific with your let dataforcell = dataArrayOrWhatever[indexPath.row] i dont understand

Comment: @E.Huckabee this answer should help your question. If you only want show different data on each cell you only need a `Dictionary` from indexPath.row . `I just want to put a button, two images and a couple labels (2-3) for each cell (there will be about 12 cells and I need them to have different data for each) ` or you asking about the custom cell. Not clear to me

Comment: i am making a character selection screen

Comment: in my question i said 12 but that will change when i update with more characters to play please check my edited answer for some new info

Comment: You only have one array right, then have you try this answer? . You need get a Dictionary of `indexPath.row` from your array then show it based their index.

Comment: So, first of all you need to think about the differences between characters views. Are all the views the same but only change the name, some stats, an image? If they are very similar you can use the same custom cell, and you only have to pass different data to each view. If the cell will change drastically you should declare diferent custom cells, but it isnt as efficient due to iOS won't be able to reuse the cells. 

About "dataArrayOrWhatever" it is an object with the data of all characters in order to be able to fetch data programmatically with an didentifier, in this case the row ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example you can follow :

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

let myButton : UIButton = {
    let btn = UIButton(type: .system)
    btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    btn.setTitle("My button", for: .normal)
    return btn
}()

override init(frame: CGRect){
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupViews()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func setupViews(){
    // Add subViews to your custom cell
    addSubview(myButton)
    myButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    myButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    myButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    myButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
}

}
```

Next step, you have to register cell class  like this in viewDidLoad:

```
collectionView.register(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "customCell")
```

Last step, in cellForItemAt function you define :

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomViewCell
        return cell
```

Comment: tried this its giving me an error " Ambiguous reference to member 'collectionView(_:numberOfItemsInSection:)'"

Comment: I think you should read more documents about collectionView (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17856055/creating-a-uicollectionview-programmatically)

Comment: what im trying to do is make a character selection screen and each cell displays the character portrait and stats, price, etc. and when you tap on the character you want it pushes to a different view controller (i know its possible because angry birds the app has it in its level select menu) is this possible with collection views or should i use something else