# CollectionView with multiple different cells, registered in other CollectionViews

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I have two separate view controllers.

In `ViewController1`, I have a `CollectionView1` and a cell that works fine. I set up the cell using `storyboard` with `ReuseIdentifier "Cell1"`.

In `ViewController2`, I have another `CollectionView2` and a different cell that works fine. I set up the cell also using `storyboard` with `ReuseIdentifier "Cell2"`.

Both cells have custom cell classes, `UserCell1` and `UserCell2`, and work fine within their separate `CollectionViews`.

Now, for the 2nd cell in the `CollectionView2`, I want to use the cell from the first collection view `(ie. IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0))`.

In `CollectionView2`, I want:

```
IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0) -> "Cell1"
IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0) -> "Cell2"
```

On `ViewController2`, within the `cellForItemAt`, I have tried using formula that indicates which cell to `dequeue` at each `index`. However, it is telling me that the cell from the first `ViewController` is not registered... but that same cell is working within its home `CollectionView`, so the `ReuseIdentifier` is clearly working.

Within `cellForItemAt (numberOfRowsInSection = 2):`

```
if indexPath == IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0) {
                guard let cell1 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell1", for: indexPath) as? UserCell1 else { return UICollectionViewCell() }
                cell1.configure(user: selectedUser)
                return cell1
            } else if indexPath == IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0) {
                guard let cell2 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell2", for: indexPath) as? UserCell2 else { return UICollectionViewCell() }
                cell2.configure(user: selectedUser)
                return cell2
            } else {
            return UICollectionViewCell()
            }
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier Cell1 - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
```

Thanks in advance!!!! This is driving me crazy :(

Comment: each cell needs to be registered for each table/collectionview. If you plan on using 2 cells in one collectionview. Both need to be registered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the good practice to your code is to define each cell in XIB not in storyboard, this will help you to reuse both of cells in any collection view by registering them from code, you can see example here:

[How to load custom cell ( xib) in UICollectionView cell using swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37315466/how-to-load-custom-cell-xib-in-uicollectionview-cell-using-swift)

if you need to define the cell in storyboard for some reason, then you need to declare two prototype cell in each collectionView2

see the following screen, we have one collection view with number of items = 2 and we should give unique ReuseIdentifier for each cell

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To use a `UICollectionViewCell` in a `UICollectionView`, you must first `register` the `cell` with `collectionView`.

**Why `Cell1` is working in `CollectionView1` and not in `CollectionView2`?**

Incase you've created the `cell` in the same `collectionView` you're using, the `registering cell` part can be skipped. But if you want to use it in some other `collectionView`, `registering the cell` is mandatory to get that working. This is the reason `Cell1` is working perfectly in `CollectionView1` and not in `CollectionView2`.

Since you want to use both `Cell1` and `Cell2` in `CollectionView2`, so both the `cells` must be `registered` with it.

But the issue is you've created `Cell1` in the `CollectionView1` itself inside the `storyboard`.

1. So first you need to create a `.xib file` and move `Cell1` into it. Let's name the `.xib file` as `Cell1.xib`.

**Suggestion:** You must create custom `UICollectionViewCell` inside `.xib file` so you can use it elsewhere as well.

2. Next you need to register `Cell1` with `CollectionView1` in `ViewController1` and `CollectionView2` in `ViewController2` in `viewDidLoad()` itself.

In `ViewController1`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    CollectionView1.register(UINib(nibName: "Cell1", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell1")
}
```

In `ViewController2`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    CollectionView2.register(UINib(nibName: "Cell1", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell1")
}
```

Similarly you can register other type of `cells` with `collectionView` as well. Try implementing this and let me know in case you still face any issues.