# How to fix fatal error in UICollectionView cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have `MasterViewController` with `UICollectionView` in `storyboard`. I use this code for my `UICollectionView`:

**MasterViewController:**

```
class MasterViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, URLSessionDownloadDelegate, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKStoreProductViewControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView?

fileprivate var currentPage: Int = 0
    fileprivate var pageSize: CGSize {
        let layout = UPCarouselFlowLayout()
        var pageSize = layout.itemSize
        pageSize.width += layout.minimumLineSpacing
        return pageSize
    }

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.addCollectionView()
        self.setupLayout()
}

func setupLayout(){

        let pointEstimator = RelativeLayoutUtilityClass(referenceFrameSize: self.view.frame.size)

        self.collectionView?.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        self.collectionView?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: pointEstimator.relativeHeight(multiplier: 0.1754)).isActive = true
        self.collectionView?.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        self.collectionView?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: pointEstimator.relativeHeight(multiplier: 0.6887)).isActive = true

        self.currentPage = 0
    }

    func addCollectionView(){

        let pointEstimator = RelativeLayoutUtilityClass(referenceFrameSize: self.view.frame.size)

        let layout = UPCarouselFlowLayout()

        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: pointEstimator.relativeWidth(multiplier: 0.73333), height: 400)

        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal

        self.collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)

        self.collectionView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.collectionView?.delegate = self
        self.collectionView?.dataSource = self

        self.collectionView?.register(MasterViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")


        let spacingLayout = UPCarouselFlowLayout()
        spacingLayout.spacingMode = UPCarouselFlowLayoutSpacingMode.overlap(visibleOffset: 20)
    }
```

**MasterViewCell:**

```
class MasterViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    let customView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        return view
    }()
    var cellImageView: UIImageView!


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.addSubview(self.customView)

        self.customView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        self.customView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        self.customView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
        self.customView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true


    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

**RelativeLayoutUtilityClass:**

```
class RelativeLayoutUtilityClass {

    var heightFrame: CGFloat?
    var widthFrame: CGFloat?

    init(referenceFrameSize: CGSize){
        heightFrame = referenceFrameSize.height
        widthFrame = referenceFrameSize.width
    }

    func relativeHeight(multiplier: CGFloat) -> CGFloat{

        return multiplier * self.heightFrame!
    }

    func relativeWidth(multiplier: CGFloat) -> CGFloat{
        return multiplier * self.widthFrame!

    }
```

But I have this error in `MasterViewCell`: `*Thread 1: Fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented*`

How to fix it?

Comment: Click the button that says “fix”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't implemented the `init(coder:)` initialiser, as you can see here:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

You seem to be loading some cells from the storyboard, so you must not just use `fatalError` here.

The implementation should be quite simple. You can just do the same thing as what you do in the `init(frame:)` initialiser:

```
class MasterViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    let customView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        return view
    }()
    var cellImageView: UIImageView!


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        self.addSubview(self.customView)

        self.customView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        self.customView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        self.customView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
        self.customView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It is works! But now I have error in `cell.cellImageView.image = UIImage(named: "1.jpg")` - `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value` And I can't fix it? What is the problem? How to fix?

Comment: @user Is there an image view in the cell in the storyboard? If so, you need to mark `cellImageView` as `@IBOutlet` and connect the outlet.

Comment: I have imageView in collection view cell in storyboard. In cell class I have the code: `@IBOutlet weak var cellImageView: UIImageView!`. But I have same error - `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: @user You did not connect the outlet in the storyboard. Right click on your cell in the storyboard. Then drag the circle next to "cellImageView" to the image view.

Comment: I connected the outlet in the storyboard (filled circle to the left of the line). Now I reconnect imageView. Doesn't work.

Comment: @user Oh well, then maybe try using a separate xib file? I always did it like this. You can start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37315466/how-to-load-custom-cell-xib-in-uicollectionview-cell-using-swift).

Comment: I remove this line `self.collectionView?.register(MasterViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")` all work fine